# Adding if Auth in custom 404 blade file in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In 404.blade.php, I wanna add `@if(auth()->user()->type == 'admin')` but it doesn't have auth variable in it. How to add it?

```
@if(auth()->getDefaultDriver() == 'admin')
<a href="{{ url('admin') }}">Back to Main Page</a>
@else
<a href="{{ url('home') }}">Back to Main Page</a>
@endif
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you running?

Comment: my version is laravel 8.x

Answer (score 2):

one way (of many)

```
 @if(Auth::user()->type == 'admin')
    <a href="{{ url('admin') }}">Back to Main Page</a>
@else
  <a href="{{ url('home') }}">Back to Main Page</a>
@endif
```

Comment: tried that one earlier but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

## Global middleware for error pages

You can move the `StartSession` middleware to the global middleware section.

This can be achieved by moving `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` from `protected $middlewareGroups['web']` to `protected $middleware[]`

In **app/Http/kernel.php**:

```php
// From
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, // <-- this class
        ...
    ],
];


// To
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ...
];
```

Comment: yes it worked. but I using this ```@if(auth()->getDefaultDriver() == 'admin')``` because in auth I used two tables. I tried this ```\Auth::getDefaultDriver() == 'admin'``` but it didn't work. I edited the question above